# Client options for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Are there any client options for querying a SQL Server database other than SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: What are you specifically looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fan of [sql dbx](http://www.sqldbx.com/), it's fast and light, but the free version is limited to only 1 connection. I use it for sql server, oracle and sybase.

Answer (score 2):

Massive list of SQL Server tools here:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx

Web tool available:

http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/

SQL Server Express Utility:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fa87e828-173f-472e-a85c-27ed01cf6b02&DisplayLang=en

Answer (score 1):

SQLCMD.exe is included with MSSQL when you install the tools, but most people use SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Redgate tools are my favorite. But most of them are paid versions and expensive.
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/